# Backbone: Navigate does not hit the specified route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Calling navigate after saving a model.

```
this.model.save({},{
        success: function(model, response, options){
            Backbone.history.navigate('getCampaigns', {tigger: true});
        }
      });
```

But it never hits the specified route.

**Route class**

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":"home",
        "login":"login",
        "getCampaigns":"getCampaigns"
    },
    start: function() {
        Backbone.history.start({pushState:true});
    },
    home: function() {
        var loginView = new LoginView({model: loginModel});
        loginView.render();
        $(".container").append(loginView.el);
    }, 
    login: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    getCampaigns: function() {
        this.dashboardList.fetch();
        $('.container').html(this.dashboardListView.render().el);
    }
});

var app = new Router();
app.start();
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `this.model.save` succeeded ?

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE Yes. Model get succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code :

```
Backbone.history.navigate('getCampaigns', {trigger: true}); // not {tigger: true}
```